# grep with -P (=PCRE) and ext regex pattern (?(cond)yes-pat) does output line despite non-match, what do I wrong?

Tags: regex, grep

I am using grep version

```
grep (GMU grep) 3.0
```

and I have tried following test code with these results:

```
echo "ab" | grep -P '(?<=a)b'; WE_retcod=$?
```

yields

ab (b is colored)

retcode is 0

ok

```
echo "ab" | grep -P '(?<=c)b'; WE_retcod=$?
```

yields

no output

retcode is 1

ok

```
echo "ab" | grep -P '(?(?<=a)b)'; WE_retcod=$?
```

yields

ab (b is colored)

retcode is 0

ok

```
echo "ab" | grep -P '(?(?<=c)b)'; WE_retcod=$?
```

yields

ab (b is not colored)

retcode is 0

wrong

I think, grep should output nothing an exit code should be 1.

What I have done false?

Regards

Comment: You are missing a closing `'` in all examples

Comment: to Arkadiusz: Thak you and my excuse me: the missing single quote is only in my posted question, it is a typo. I am going on to edit and correct. Regards.